# adjust css in InputLabel

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a drop down list, an example of which I took from the mui documentation. But I need to customize this drop-down list a little. The problem is pictured below.

[image]

I would like to place the inscription "choose format" in the middle of the field and change the font size.

```
    return (
      <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 150 }}  size="small">
        <InputLabel>Сhoose format</InputLabel>
        <Select
          value={age}
          label="Сhoose format"
          onChange={handleChange}
          sx={{
            "& .MuiSelect-select": {
              paddingTop: 0.1,
              paddingBottom: 0.4,
              
          },
     }}
        >

        </Select>
      </FormControl>

  );
```

Comment: Did you try to remove the `paddingTop` and `paddingBottom`, if it doesn't work, could you please reproduce the issue on a codesandbox so we can debug?

Comment: @Mina yes, I tried it.But I need this field of exactly the same height as it is now. https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-mestorf-jcx449

Comment: What is the appropriate height you need, and do you want to change the font size to be appropriate for this height?

Answer (score 0):

**Font Size**

In your `styles.css` file add the following:

```
.MuiFormLabel-root {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

This will allow you to adjust the font size for the placeholder specifically.

**Alignment**

To ensure the placeholder is in the middle, simply adjust the fontsize in the component like so:

```
export default function App() {
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState("");

  return (
    <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 150 }} size="small">
      <InputLabel>Сhoose format</InputLabel>
      <Select
        value={age}
        label="Сhoose format"
        sx={{
          "& .MuiSelect-select": {
            fontSize: 25 // Matches the font size to the styles.css
          }
        }}
      >
        <MenuItem value={10}>.txt</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={20}>.docx</MenuItem>
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

Or if you don't want to add the change in your style.css file or if you want to use styled components you can add it directly in your existing `sx` in the `FromControl` component

`<FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 150, ".MuiFormLabel-root": { fontSize: 25}  }} size="small">'`

Comment: That's a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the line height and text size of the label to position it inside the box.

**CSS:**

```
label.MuiFormLabel-root {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
}
```

Use the `line-height` to control the vertical position inside the box, adjust both values to your liking.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-moore-u5c50e?file=/src/styles.css)

Comment: Yes, thanks, it partially works. Just tell me why when I start changing the line-height something is superimposed on the text and it starts to disappear

Comment: In case the line height is lower than the font size, the lower part of the text might get cropped, if that's what you mean?

Comment: Yes, I meant it